# What does ?. mean in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I know the if I have something like product.id == 1 ? stuff : not stuff. That means if id = 1, then choose "stuff". If not, then choose "not stuff". What does the following mean:

```
product?.id.name
```

Comment: It checks to see if product is null and if not it accesses the id property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**`?`** Means safe **[`navigation operator`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)**

From **`Docs`**

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here
>   it is, protecting against a view render failure if the currentHero is
>   null.

This specifically means that if the value you are binding to the view is null then it should return null else the actual value, so that you dont get any issues while rendering the template.

In the above sample code you provided ,

**`product?.id.name`**

it checks whether produce object exists and then it will check if there is an id.
since you dont have  **`?`** after id. **`it will throw an error "cannot read property of 'name' undefined".`**

Comment: `?.` short-circuits. (If `product` doesn't exist, the expression evaluates to null and `product.id` is never evaluated.) It shouldn't throw an error unless `product` exists and `product.id` doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

Literally this means:

```
((product == null) ? null: product.id.name)
```

So if `product` is null then return `null` otherwise return the whole value.

[image]

If we have:

```
product?.id?.name
```

then we should expect something like:

```
((product == null) ? null: ((product.id == null) ? null: product.id.name))
```

If you're doubt then you can always check how it looks like after angular compiler:

For more details see docs:

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 4):

Just syntaxic sugar for `product && product.id.name`

Answer (score 3):

Angular safe navigation operator (?.) prevent to navigate throw null or undefined component property

let assume you have a property in you component named `person` and it `null` or `undefined`

```
{{person.name}} // in case of null Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

{{person?.name}} // working fine
```